# string in request body's length is always limited in Express&&bodyparser

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest, string-length, body-parser

I got a very annoying issue in express4&body parser.

In the front-end I got a form with an input containing a very long string, **say 5,000,000 in length, which is close to 5MB.**

Once I submit this form, I print this input in express routes: console.log(req.body.inputname.length), the weird thing is **the length is always limited to 1,048,553**, which is very close to 1MB. No error/exception occurs.

**I already set bodyparser limit size to 50MB** and I tested it with input(type =file), when I upload large size file it's working so I guess size limit is not an issue.

Basically I upload an image in front-end to input(type=file), and then in front-end I use fileReader to convert it into base64 string and submit that string through post request. That is why I can get such long string.

***front-end(I used jade and Vue)***

```
form(method='post',action="/upload",enctype='multipart/form-data')
  input(type='file', @change='previewImages($event)', multiple='multiple')
  input.hidden-input(type='hidden' name='imagesArray' v-model='imagesArray')

script.
  //In vue instance,
  data:{
  imagesArray:[];
   }
  methods{
    previewImages(event){
       function readAndPreview(){
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
             ourVueInstance.imagesArray.push(e.target.result);},false);
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }  
     [].forEach.call(event.target.files, readAndPreview);
    }
 }
```

***router(using express app)***

```
app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
//imageArray is converted to string, and its length is now limited to 1048553
console.log(req.body.imagesArray.length)
})
```

***bodyparser settings***

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb',length:'1000000000' })); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb',extended: true,parameterLimit:50000,length:'1000000000'}));
```

Added:
  ***server.js***

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var sticky  = require('sticky-cluster');
var util    = require('./util/util.js');
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var i18n = require('i18n-express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var morgan =  require('morgan');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var config = require('./config/config.json');
var log = require('./util/log.js').getLogger(__filename);
var passport = require('passport');
var validator =  require('express-validator');
var port = config.our_SERVER_PORT;
var sslport = config.our_SERVER_SSL_PORT;

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

//var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
require('./config/passport');

// running applications on the master process
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(morgan('dev'));  // log every request to the console
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(config.IMAGE_BASE_PATH));

//initialize the DB connections
//load configuration details from the server configuration JSON
var dbURL = config.DB_URL;
log.info("Initializing the DB connection. " + dbURL);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(dbURL, {useMongoClient:true});

app.use(cookieParser(config.SESSION.SESSION_SECRET)); // read cookies (needed for auth)

app.use(session({
    secret: config.SESSION.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({url: dbURL}),
    cookie: {maxAge: config.SESSION.COOKIE_MAXAGE_MS}
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(validator());

//sign in protection
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    res.locals.session = req.session;

    //To avoid undefined total quantity in topnavbarMain's cart
    if(!req.session.cart){
        req.session.cart={};
    }
    next();
});

//init i18n after cookie-parser
app.use(i18n({
    translationsPath: __dirname +  '/i18n',
    siteLangs: config.SUPPORTED_LANGUAGE,
    cookiename:'ulang'
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb',length:'1000000000' })); // get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb',extended: true,parameterLimit:50000,length:'1000000000'}));


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.set('view engine', "pug");
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);

app.use(flash());  // use connect-flash for flash message stored in session

//CA certificate for HTTPS
var options = {};
var http, https;

// sticky options
var stickySSLOptions = {
    concurrency: require('os').cpus().length,
    //concurrency:1,
    port: config.our_SERVER_SSL_PORT,
    debug: true
};

// sticky options
var stickyOptions = {
    concurrency: require('os').cpus().length,
    //concurrency:1,
    port: config.our_SERVER_PORT,
    debug: true
};

// configuration enables the CA cert with SSL enabled
if (config.CA_CERT.SSL_ENABLED) {

    sticky(
        // server initialization function
        function(callback) {
            options = {
                ca   : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/' + config.CA_CERT.SSL_CA),
                key  : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/' + config.CA_CERT.SSL_KEY),
                cert : fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert/' + config.CA_CERT.SSL_CERT),
                passphrase: config.CA_CERT.passphrase
            };

            https = require('https').createServer(options, app);

            callback(https);
        },

        stickySSLOptions
    );

}
else {
    // non SSL
    sticky(
        function(callback) {
            http = require('http').createServer(app);

            callback(http);
        },

        stickyOptions
    );
}

//routes
//require routes goes here. I will not list them for space. 


/******************************************************
 * error handlers
 ******************************************************/
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    let err = new Error('.............');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.errMsg = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('common/error');
});


//check if we are running master process
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Listen for dying workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        // Replace the dead worker
        console.log('Worker %d died :(', worker.id);
        log.info("Worker " +  worker.id + " died. Replace with a new worker to serve for the application.");
        cluster.fork();
    });
}
```

Any thoughts on this? Any solution/try will be appreciated, Many thanks!

Comment: Could not reproduce this in my system. Can you post your full code including the route?

Comment: @Vasan Hi Vasan I updated my question and paste my code. If any problems please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's posting the entire data properly? Can you view it in browser's console? Also, is there a proxy/other layer between client and node? I tried with a simple html file with textarea and posted the data to local node. Used your route and body parser settings and it works absolutely fine (prints 5000000 on node side).

Comment: Also, why do you need the intermediate base64 conversion anyway? Why not just upload it as a file and use busboy (or similar) on node side to handle it?

Comment: @Vasan Hi Vasan thanks for you reply! Answer to your questions:1. The entire data is complete in the front end I already checkedit; 2. There is a isloggedin function in the route however even if I delete it code still not working;  3. base64 is not a good practice, but because fileList is ReadOnly in front-end and I cannot operate images as my wish(eg:delete single img) and I do not want to import a third-party uploader at this time. So I chose to use base64 conversion. 4. I double checked my server.js but cannot find anything wrong. Could you please have a brief look at it? Thanks!